# XML Meta Schema

Tags: xml, xsd, schema, metaprogramming, homoiconicity

Since XML schemata (XSD) are themselves XML files, it should be possible to build
a schema of a schema (meta-schema), right?

I'm struggling to accomplish that feat.

I would like to create a schema that describes a schema
with one root `complexType` containing a sequence of `simpleTypes`.

Answer (score 2):

Akoma-Ntoso is an example of such a meta-schema:

> "We can say that Akoma Ntoso is a meta-schema that allows you to build your own schema: it provides the building blocks for different organisations to use to build their own very individual schemas. Having organisations using similar building blocks, identifying these blocks in a similar fashion goes a long way to allow greater integration and exchange of documents as well as reusability of software tools..."
>
> Akoma Ntoso (“linked hearts” in the Akan language of West Africa) defines a set of simple technology-neutral electronic representations in XML format of parliamentary, legislative and judiciary documents.

It uses two abstractions, `extends`:

> The element `extends` is a metadata element specifying a reference to a source extended by the argument being described.

- an extension is a derived rule that adds in a controlled way new features
  to a base rule, so that all documents that are correct according to the
  derived rule can be validated against the base rule by removing the
  additional features. The set of valid documents according to the derived
  rule is a controlled superset of the set of valid documents according to the
  base rule.

and `restricts`:

> The element `restricts` is a metadata element specifying a reference to a source restricted by the argument being described.

- a restriction is a derived rule that is stricter than the base one, so that all
  documents that are correct according to the derived rule are also valid
  according to the base one: the set of valid documents for the derived rule
  is a mathematical subset of the set of valid documents according to the
  base rule.

**References**

- [Akoma Ntoso | Akoma Ntoso Site](http://www.akomantoso.org/)
- [Akoma Ntoso Version 1.0 Part 1: XML Vocabulary](http://docs.oasis-open.org/legaldocml/akn-core/v1.0/csprd01/part1-vocabulary/akn-core-v1.0-csprd01-part1-vocabulary.html)
- [Akoma Ntoso Version 1.0. Part 2: Specifications](http://docs.oasis-open.org/legaldocml/akn-core/v1.0/csprd01/part2-specs/akn-core-v1.0-csprd01-part2-specs.html)
- [AKOMA NTOSO Technical Documentation - Alphabetical Listing](http://examples.akomantoso.org/alphabetical.html)
- [XMLSchema Documentation browser: Akoma Ntoso](http://sinatra.cirsfid.unibo.it/XSDocViewer/)
- [Customizing Akoma Ntoso - Prof. Fabio Vitali University of Bologna (pdf)](https://publicadministration.un.org/Parliaments/Portals/0/conferences/capetown2006/05%20Fabio%20Vitali%20-%20Customizing%20Akoma%20Ntoso.pdf)
- [The Systems Biology Markup Language (SBML): Language Specification for Level 3 Version 1 Core](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5451324/)
- [How to verify that one XSD schema is a subset of another XSD schema?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14286071/)

Answer (score 1):

Of course you can build your own schema for this purpose. 
A good startingpoint would be the official one
[from the W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-1/#normative-schemaSchema)

I would suggest do make two validation runs: one with the unchanged schema and a second run with a simplified, custom made schema.
This custom schema can be a stripped-down version of the original only containing the additional constraints. The rest can be allowed via wildcards (`<xs:any>`)

Answer (score 0):

So, you want to write an XSD to validate that an XSD is valid? Well, why do that when there is an Xsd Validator:

http://www.w3.org/2001/03/webdata/xsv

Comment: Thanks, but it should not only be valid, but restricted to the form described in the last sentence above.

Comment: I see, well, I believe the 'xs' namespace will be the restricting factor here.