# XML Schema: define type of types

Tags: xml, validation, types, xsd

I'd like to define a schema that contains elements specifying an XML schema type. This question may be related to the [XML Schema for schemas](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-1/#normative-schemaSchema) and this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3051770/xml-meta-schema).

Here's what I have so far:

```
<xs:complexType name="metatype">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="datatype" type="datatype" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
      <xs:element name="location" type="locationtype" minOccurs="0"maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
      <xs:element name="alias" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:ID" use="required"/>
    <xs:attribute name="editable" type="xs:boolean" default="false" use="optional"/>
    <xs:attribute name="forcedvisible" type="xs:boolean" default="false" use="optional"/>
</xs:complexType>
```

where datatype is:

```
<xs:complexType name="datatype">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="restriction">
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="enumeration">
              <xs:complexType>
                <xs:attribute name="value" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
              </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
          </xs:sequence>
          <xs:attribute name="base" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
          <!-- type xs:string is not accurate for XML Schema type -->
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

Instead of declaring datatype I'd like to use the `localSimpleType` in the [Schema for schemas](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-1/#normative-schemaSchema) or at least the `simpleRestrictionType` but my XML Schema editor (Visual Studio) does not seem to recognize these types. Is there another XML Schema document that I need to reference? I'd really like to avoid defining the whole XML Schema `simpleType` element and its subtags for restrictions, etc..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should be able to write a schema that imports the S4S and references types defined in it. It's entirely possible that some tools will object, however.

One thing you shouldn't do is try to process a modified S4S, or to add extra components into the XSD namespace. Schema-aware tools are entitled to treat everything in the S4S as axiomatic, and presenting them with definitions that differ from their built-in knowledge of these components could cause untold havoc.

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to use xsd or invent your own and write your own parser as well?

You can define types with or without restrictions, or you can add a local restriction to a defined type in a known namespace which usually includes xs.

Local restrictions are best for one offs, if you use it more than once, define a new type for DRY (donot repeat yourself)

e.g.

```
<xs:simpleType name="mySimpleTypeA">
  <xs:restriction base = "xs:string">
    <xs:enumeration value ="on"/>
    <xs:enumeration value = "off"/>
  </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

and

```
<xs:complexType name="myComplexTypeA>
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="someElementName">
      <xs:simpleType>
        <xs:restriction base ="xs:string">
          <xs:minLength ="8"/>
        </xs:restriction>
      </xs:simpleType>
    </xs:element>
  </xs:sequence>
  <xs:attribute name="someAttributeName" use="required" type="mySimpleTypeA"/>
</xs:complexType>
```

Then you can use them as in

```
<xs:element name = "Fred" type ="myComplexTypeA"/>
```

calling your element restriction, isn't going to make it one...

Oh off the top of my head this, didn't validate it, but it should be close.